# How to insert a heading before the group of mapped items created on the same date inside the map function?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to map an array of objects like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';

const designItems = () => {
  const itemsList = [
    {
      id: 30,
      name: "Item 30",
      created_at: "2020-12-09T09:23:58.936Z"
    }, // etc.
  ];

  const items = itemslist.map((item, i) => {
    const monthName = moment(item.created_at, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]').format('MMMM');
    const yearName = moment(item.created_at, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]').format('YYYY');

    return (
      <p key={item.id}>{item.name}</p>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {items}
    </div>
  );
};

export default designItems;
```

The array `itemsList` is sorted by descending date the items were created at (created_at).

Is there a way to insert a heading containing `monthName` and `yearName` before each group of paragraphs that were created at same year and month so the output looks like this?

```
<div>
  <h3>December 2020</h3>
  <p>Item 30</p>
  <p>Item 29</p>
  <h3>November 2020</h3>
  <p>Item 28</p>
  <p>Item 27</p>
  ...
<div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how are you?

You can create a structure that groups the items by month/year. You can write a function to do that first and then you iterate over this structure. For example:

```js
function groupItemsByYearAndMonth(items) {
  const grouped = {}

  items.forEach(item => {
    const yearName = moment(item.created_at, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]').format('YYYY');
    const monthName = moment(item.created_at, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]').format('MMMM');
    const key = `${monthName} ${yearName}`;
    
    // if the key does not exists, we create it
    if (!grouped[key]) {
      grouped[key] = [];
    }
    
    grouped[key].push(item);
  })

  return grouped;
}
```

The function above will return an object in which the keys are the `year+month` and the value of each key will be an array of items, for example:

```js
{
  'December 2020': [
    {name: 'Item 30'},
    {name: 'Item 29'},
  ]
  'November 2020': [
    {name: 'Item 28'},
    {name: 'Item 27'},
  ]
}
```

Now you can iterate over the object using `Object.entries(groupedItems).map([yearAndMonth, items])`. Se the example bellow:

```js
const App = () => {
  const list = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Item 1",
      created_at: "2020-12-09T09:23:58.936Z"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Item 2",
      created_at: "2020-12-08T09:23:58.936Z"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Item 3",
      created_at: "2020-11-09T09:23:58.936Z"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "Item 4",
      created_at: "2020-11-08T09:23:58.936Z"
    },
  ];
  const groupedItems = groupItemsByYearAndMonth(list);

  const renderItems = items => {
    return items.map(item => (
      <p key={item.name}>{item.name}</p>
    ))
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {Object.entries(groupedItems).map(([yearMonth, items]) => (
        <>
          <h3>{yearMonth}</h3>
          {renderItems(items)}
        </>        
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have create this [Code Pen](https://codepen.io/csilva2810/pen/bGwwWXg) so you can check it out. :)